# Hiding figures and tables from document structure in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

In MS Word it is possible to show the document structure on the left side?

Is it possible to remove the figures/tables from that list (and keep only the paragraph captions)?

Comment: "Document Structure"? "figures/tables"? It sounds like you have a "Table of Figures" (References | Insert Table of Figures") and you want it to show only paragraph captions?

Comment: @jJack I think OP is referring to the Navigation View.

Comment: @jJack I don't mean document structure but probably Navigation Window; I'm using a Dutch version so I don't know the literal English translation. It's a pane on the left side of the document itsself that shows now only paragraphs but also tables and figures and it clutters up the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you mean "Document map" which can be found under View as seen below.

[image]

When I tried it the headings appeared in the map, but things like tables or captions did not.

[image]

Perhaps what has happened is those caption paragraphs have had their styles modified so that the **Paragraph Format -> Outline Level** is set to **Level 1** to **Level 9**. This will cause them to appear in the map. If you modify the outline level back to **Body Text** they will not longer appear in the map.

Comment: Sorry it took some time before checking ... I have been busy with other things. But your answer really worked so I'm glad I have now a clear document map. My document is now 125 pages so it helps a lot with navigating. Thanks!

Comment: A little more detail for my case: Select the paragraph that is connected to one of the figures in the document map. Right click and select "Paragraph..." Under "Indents and Spacing", select Outline level to be "Body Text" and click OK. This updated all the figures in the document, resolving the issue.